# Auto close program after X seconds inactivity (in that program)

Tags: autohotkey

Using AutoHotkey, I want to auto close a program (e.g. Firefox) after X seconds of inactivity (in that program--i.e. mouse or keyboard activity possibly elsewhere, but none in that program).

What code should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Firefox after it has been inactive for 20 seconds:

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, close_inactive_Firefox_window, 1000 ; 1 second timer
return

    close_inactive_Firefox_window:
If !WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
    time++ ; checks the number in the variable "time" and increases it by 1 every 1 second (in accordance with the timer period)
else
    time := 0     ; reset
If (time = 20)    ; 20 seconds
{
    WinClose, ahk_exe firefox.exe
    time := 0     ; reset
}
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#operators

**EDIT**

If you want to scroll the inactive Firefox window without getting it closed, add this to the above code:

```
#If MouseIsOver("ahk_exe firefox.exe")

    ~WheelUp::
    ~WheelDown::
        time := 0 ; reset
    return

#If

MouseIsOver(WinTitle){
    MouseGetPos,,, Win
    return WinExist(WinTitle . " ahk_id " . Win)
}
```

Comment: What you are detecting is FOCUS. If you have the Firefox window opened, click on another window, but hover your mouse over Firefox, you can still scroll the browser, but it'll close because it never got focus. Maybe this is enough for what OP wants, but it has caveats.

Comment: @Nelson,  see EDIT in this answer.

Comment: `WinClose` also closes only one window, so if multiple Firefox windows are opened, it'll only close one of them. You're coding all the detection code from scratch and trying to handle all scenarios. If force close is needed, may need to use `WinKill` instead, but that's going to cancel downloads, and it's going to trigger the "recover tabs" prompt on next open, etc. etc.

Comment: To close all windows create a group, etc. etc.

Comment: @user3419297: Your answer worked perfectly well for me and I have been happily using it. You can ignore Nelson's criticisms.

Answer (score 1):

It's far too complicated to create with such constraints.

If it is simply computer closes Firefox after 15 minutes of no activity, then that's fine. However, there is no built-in measurement of "no activity within a program", so you'll have to do that part yourself. You will then have to process every keystroke, mouse movement, mouse click, and classify that as Firefox activity or not, and then closing it when 15 minutes of inactivity has occurred.

Comment: I thought there was a WinActive function?

Comment: That function doesn't do what you think it does. Here is the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm): it simply detects whether a Window exists or not. There is no tracker for how long it has been inactive.